# Could not find or load main class weblogic.server in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle

I am facing the below error.

"Error: Could not find or load main class weblogic.server" in eclipse.

I am using eclipse luna & weblogic server 10.0.3 for my application.

The inbuilt script setWLSEnv.sh (C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\server\bin) is setting a different classpath. The below path is not there in my desktop.

CLASSPATH="C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_wls1036\profiles\default\sys_manifest_classpath\weblogic_patch.jar

I guess that is why it is not able to find the class. 
How can I set correct classpath of this.
Tried searching to set classpath in weblogic admin console. but not able to find it.

Any help will be really appreciated!!.. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

When execute setWLSEnv.sh the command must be: ". ./setWLSEnv.sh" instead of "./setWLSEnv.sh" (there are 2 seperate dot). Then you should be fine doing next step

Comment: This worked for me, but why? My knoledge on bash is minimal. What an addition dot means?